# Upload images to cloud and then paste the respective link to a respective dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cloud, python-camelot

I've PDFs with tables and the image diagram related to the content of tables.
Both, table and image on a single page.

I've extracted the Tables using the Camelot library. And also images using Fitz library. **Using Python**

Now I want to upload those images(.png) to any possible cloud service and provide the web link of the respective image to the Dataframe of the respective table.

Please help.

[This is how a single Page of PDF looks line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MQQQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of any public cloud, you can use S3 to store images using [BOTO3](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html#storing-data) (python library).

sample code to store images in AWS S3 bucket:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'your-bucket-name'
file_name = 'location-of-your-image'
key_name = 'name-of-image-in-s3'
s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket, key_name)
```

To obtain the uploaded file url, you can construct it as:

```
s3_url = f"https://{bucket}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{file_name}"
```

and store **s3_url** in dataframe.